# ¿Como puedo aplicar un for en mi script?

Tags: linux, bucle-for, bash, script

Mi objetivo es que con un for aplicar un bucle en el cual si ingresan una opción no valida vuelvan a formular las preguntas

```
 75 echo "1)Contenedores existentes"
 76 sleep 1
 77 #$(lxc list > contenedores.txt)
 78 $(lxc list | sed '/+---------/d' > estado_actual.txt)
 79 cat estado_actual.txt
 80 #for linea in $(cat estado_actual.txt);
 81 #        do
 82 #                echo $linea
 83 #        done
 84 sleep 1
 85 #       if [ $? -ne 0];then
 86 #                       echo "lxc list > contenedores.txt"$(date +%d-%m-%y-%T) >> errores.log
 87 #               fi
 88
 89
 90         read -p "Escribe el nombre del contenedor ya existente 
 91 " CONT
 92
 93                         echo "Elije si quieres detenerlo,iniciarlo, gestionar la RAM o CPU"
 94  
 95                 sleep 1
 96  
 97         read -p "Pulsa 1 para detenerlo, 2 para iniciarlo, 3 para gestionar la RAM o 4 para la C>
 98 " OPCION
 99
100 case $OPCION in 
101 
102         1) echo "Has elejido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
103                 detener_maquina
104         ;;
105
106         2) echo "Has elejido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
107                 iniciar_maquina 
108         ;;
109
110         3) echo "Has elejido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
111                 gestion_ram
112         ;;
113
114         4) echo "Has elejido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
115                 gestion_cpu
116         ;;
117         *) echo "Opcion no valida. Deteniedo el script" 
118                 exit;;
119
120 esac
121
```

Quiero poner un for al inicio del script para que cuando seleccione una opcion no valida me vuelva a formular las preguntas.

He utilizado diversas funciones por eso el código se ve así, en caso de que sea necesario me gustaría que me avisaran

Comment: No te vendría mejor usar un while? En este caso la condición de salida esta condicionada a la entrada, más que una iteración...

Comment: de acuerdo con @Jakala. Además, sería bueno proporcionar un [mcve]. Esto es, un código mínimo para que sea replicable, sin contener tantísima cosa que hace más difícil la comprensión.